# JEB Decompiler - Signature recognition engine

Tags: decompilation, android, java

I've been playing around with the [JEB decompiler](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/) and Android reverse engineering suite. One interesting feature they have is deobfuscation by [library code matching](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/blog/jeb-library-code-matching-for-android/) in which 3rd party libraries out there (written in Java) which have been obfuscated are recognized and matched with the original library names.

However, the plugin allows custom parameters to fine tune the accuracy of detection
. I still cant wrap my head around and understand how the option and parameters work? Could any Java language experts explain and give examples? Im using JEB 3.7

[image]

Comment: JEB is a pretty expensive software - why not ask the software company who develops JEB?